# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 87 word2vec gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

i have code

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from datetime import timedelta
from gensim.models import word2vec
start_time = time.time()
print('Training Word2Vec Model...')
sentences = word2vec.LineSentence('data/data_text.txt')
id_w2v = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, size=300, workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
id_w2v.save('model_terbaru/word2vec_300.model')
```

when i make model, i have an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File"<ipython-input-10-fc7016864a34>", line 1, in <module>

        runfile('F:/pa reza/model.py', wdir='F:/pa reza')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "F:/pa reza/model.py", line 13, in <module>
    iter=10)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 527, in **init**
    fast_version=FAST_VERSION)

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 335, in __init__
        self.build_vocab(sentences, trim_rule=trim_rule)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 480, in build_vocab
    sentences, progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1151, in scan_vocab
    for sentence_no, sentence in enumerate(sentences):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1073, in __iter__
    line = utils.to_unicode(line).split()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 359, in any2unicode

return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 87: invalid continuation byte
```

help me....

Comment: You cut the traceback a bit short. You might get faster answers if you show us which of your following lines causes the issue, not just the issue itself. I'm guessing `sentences` is `ISO-8859-1` or `ISO-8859-7` encoded or something similar. Which means `id_w2v.save()` won't be able to do ` unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)`

Comment: How was the file `data_text.txt` acquired or created? (It likely has data in some unexpected character-encoding, and the best fix may be to improve the process that created it.)